# I can't make CLOB work

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Im a beginner in using oracle CLOBs. Im trying to set an apex value using a function that will return a clob. I am running this function using sql plus and I got no error but when I used this to set the item(text area) value, it give me the `numeric or value error`. To be more clear here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION RETURN clob IS
 v_clob CLOB; 
BEGIN
   for a in 1..1000000 LOOP
      v_clob:= v_clob|| to_char(a) || '|';
   END LOOP;
RETURN v_clob;
END;
```

Is there a way on how to make this work? Is it because a text area is not enough to hold that CLOB's value or is it something else? I believe a text area item can hold lots(millions) of characters so i dont know what's wrong..

Comment: https://atulley.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/setting-and-retrieving-clob-values-in-apex/

Answer (score 1):

Small modifications to your function..

```
CREATE or replace  FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION RETURN CLOB IS
v_clob CLOB; 
BEGIN
for a in 1..100000 LOOP
v_clob:= v_clob|| to_char(a) || '|';
END LOOP;
RETURN v_clob;
END;
```

For running the function

```
select my_function() from dual
```

Comment: would this try too ? just asking .. v_clob:= v_clob|| 'a' || '|';

Comment: Thanks @Tarun. This worked using sql plus but I've got another problem. I have modified the original question.

Comment: it doesn't work @Moudiz . That concatenates the literal chracter 'a' , not the value of a

Comment: @Moudiz Yes i have tried in that function code there is a data type mismatch, we are passing integer values into 'a' variable after that we are assigning 'a' variable's data to a clob(character format) variable so i used to_char() function for overcome that mismatch.